# How to convert a Base64 string into a Bitmap image to show it in a ImageView?

Tags: android, base64, imageview

I have a Base64 String that represents a BitMap image.

I need to transform that String into a BitMap image again to use it on a ImageView in my Android app

How to do it?

This is the code that I use to transform the image into the base64 String:

```
//proceso de transformar la imagen BitMap en un String:
//android:src="c:\logo.png"
Resources r = this.getResources();
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r, R.drawable.logo);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
//String encodedImage = Base64.encode(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
encodedImage = Base64.encodeBytes(b);
```

Answer (score 430, accepted):

You can just basically revert your code using some other built in methods.

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Comment: make sure you are not passing the "data:image/jpg;base64" and pass only the image bytes.. Don't forget to change the string to bytes.. 
 photoData = photoData.substring(photoData.indexOf(",") + 1);
 byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(photoData.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
Hope it helps for someone.

Comment: as answered already 
If the encodedImage string is a JSON response, simply use Base64.URL_SAFE instead of Base64.DEAULT

Comment: To remove the data:image... for both png and jpeg try this:
`String cleanImage = base64Image.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "").replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,","");`

Answer (score 82):

To anyone who is still interested in this question:
If:
1-decodeByteArray returns null
2-Base64.decode throws bad-base64 Exception

Here is the solution:
-You should consider the value sent to you from API is Base64 Encoded and should be decoded first in order to cast it to a Bitmap object!
-Take a look at your Base64 encoded String, If it starts with

> data:image/jpg;base64

The Base64.decode won't be able to decode it, So it has to be removed from your encoded String:

```
final String encodedString = "data:image/jpg;base64, ....";                        
final String pureBase64Encoded = encodedString.substring(encodedString.indexOf(",")  + 1);
```

Now the **pureBase64Encoded** object is ready to be decoded:

```
final byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(pureBase64Encoded, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Now just simply use the line below to turn this into a **Bitmap** Object! :

> Bitmap decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0,
>   decodedBytes.length);

Or if you're using the great library **Glide**:

```
Glide.with(CaptchaFragment.this).load(decodedBytes).crossFade().fitCenter().into(mCatpchaImageView);
```

This should do the job! It wasted one day on this and came up to this solution!

**Note**: 
If you are still getting bad-base64 error consider other Base64.decode flags like Base64.URL_SAFE and so on

Comment: I got base64 from json response, used Base.64.URL_SAFE got bad-base64 error, Checked this thread and solved, Thumbs up man..

Answer (score 18):

This is a very old thread but thought to share this answer as it took lot of my development time to manage `NULL` return of `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` as @Anirudh has faced.

If the `encodedImage` string is a `JSON` response, simply use `Base64.URL_SAFE` instead of `Base64.DEAULT`

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.URL_SAFE);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Comment: i am getting a bad-base64 (IllegalArgumentException) error when using Base64.URL_SAFE. I verified the base64 string using an HTML img tag. I am seeing the image on HTML page.

Comment: Hi @mudit, did you figure out how to fix the bad-base64 exception?  If so do you mind to share?  I am having the same issue.  Have been for two days now and running out of ideas.

Comment: @ito make sure you are not passing the "data:image/jpg;base64" and pass only the image bytes.. Don't forget to change the string to bytes.. 
 photoData = photoData.substring(photoData.indexOf(",") + 1);
 byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(photoData.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

Comment: I too struggled a lot for this one word "Base64.URL_SAFE".....I was fetching as json obj ...Thanks a ton

Answer (score 15):

To check online you can use

http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

You can convert string to image like this way

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView image =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

        //encode image to base64 string
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

        //decode base64 string to image
        imageBytes = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        image.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);
    }
}
```

http://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2016/10/android-convert-image-base64-string-base64-string-image.html

Comment: Found the website very useful for figuring out if there was an issue with my code or with the image data. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 8):

This is a great sample:

```
String base64String = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAADDPmHLAA...";
String base64Image = base64String.split(",")[1];
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64Image, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

Sample found at: https://freakycoder.com/android-notes-44-how-to-convert-base64-string-to-bitmap-53f98d5e57af

This is the only code that worked for me in the past.

Comment: yeah i definitely couldn't get this working without splitting after the comma. i think this should be the accepted answer, thank you!!

Answer (score 5):

I've found this easy solution

To convert from bitmap to Base64 use this method.

```
private String convertBitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

To convert from Base64 to bitmap OR revert.

```
private Bitmap convertBase64ToBitmap(String b64) {
    byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(b64.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin you can use extension function as bellow:

```
fun String.base64ToByteCode() = Base64.decode(this.substring(this.indexOf(",")  + 1), Base64.DEFAULT)
```

and call it as bellow:

```
yourBase64String.base64ToByteCode()
```

Comment: you can replace ``this.substring(this.indexOf(",")  + 1)`` with ``substringAfter(",")``

Answer (score 1):

This **solution** is working fine for me. if you receive null please let me know.

```
private void bytesToImage(ImageView imageView, String base64String) {
        if (!base64String.isEmpty()) {
            byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    
           Glide.with(this).load(decodedByte).into(imageView);
    
            
        }
```

Comment: if you decide to use Glide you can load the base64 string directly into the imageView. there is no need to decode it yourself, just pass your base64 string to glide and it'll do the reset.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the solutions and this one worked for me

```
let temp = base64String.components(separatedBy: ",")
let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: temp[1], options: 
 .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
let decodedimage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)

yourImage.image = decodedimage
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, you can create an extension function on ImageView like below:

```
fun ImageView.loadFromBase64(encodedImageString: String) {
    try {
         val base64Image = encodedImageString.split(",")[1]
         val decodedString = Base64.decode(base64Image, Base64.DEFAULT)
         val bitmap = 
         BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString,0,decodedString.size)
         setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
         Timber.d("Error loading image from base64: ${e.message}")
    }
}
```

At the point of usage, you can easily do:

```
imageView.loadFromBase64(encodedImageString)
```