# create imageview from base64.decode

Tags: java, android, image, base64

I have this problem: I want represent a base64 string to image that come from php page in my android application (the string base64 work fine and come good) so I have done this:

```
byte[] gzipBuff = Base64.decode(json_data.getString("immagine"),0);
ByteArrayInputStream memstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(gzipBuff, 0, gzipBuff.length);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(gzipBuff.length);
baos.write(gzipBuff);

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(memstream);
ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

I don't see the imageview

Comment: Why are you creating a ByteArrayOutputStream? If this is gzipped, why are you not doing any kind of gzip decompression? Are you not seeing any exceptions?

Comment: the variable gzip is only variable if i mistake please tell me a solution because with other language like c# or vbnet i resolve very well and with few code because there i can use a memory stream so there i done :

imagebyte=Convert.FromBase64(stringa); MemoryStream ms=new MemoryStream(imagebyte,0,imagebyte.Length);

Image img=Image.FromStream(ms,True);

this work very fine but in Android i don't know Can you help me?

Thank's a lot

Comment: @Mrfalco: I'd expect it to work, although there's no point in using `baos` in the code you've given. Again, I'd expect there to be an exception if anything's wrong with the data. Have you stepped through in a debugger to check that you're getting the right data?

Comment: this is the log
03-26 11:10:07.746: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2604): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1927 objects / 136160 bytes in 119ms

03-26 11:10:29.107: INFO/System.out(2604): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: android.widget.ImageView@43e49590

03-26 11:10:29.467: INFO/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity com.falco.mysql/.TestMysql: 51094 ms (total 51094 ms)

Comment: @Mrfalco: You haven't answered whether you've inspected the data you're getting in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

A quick [Google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=android+imageview+base64) search finds one of your other duplicate questions as the first result, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837110/how-to-convert-a-base64-string-into-a-bitmap-image-to-show-it-in-a-imageview) as the second. See the [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837110/how-to-convert-a-base64-string-into-a-bitmap-image-to-show-it-in-a-imageview/4837293#4837293) answer from that question.