# Android: Converting Strings to Bitmap

Tags: android

I am trying to convert the strings to bitmap by using the Base64 and BitmapFactory but unable to convert. Please can any one help me to convert strings to bitmap.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what have you done and what problem/error are you facing?

Comment: "unable to convert" => What is happening then?

Comment: just check out this http://stackoverflow.com/q/4837110/840861

Answer (score 1):

You can convert Base64 string to byte array,

and from the Byte Array you can decode Bitmap.

Using these 2 methods.

```
byte[] arr = Base64.decode(s, options);
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, offset, length);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response i tried this but its returning null form the BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray().

Comment: Can you please suggest any other solution to convert strings to bitamp.