# to retrieve already stored image from database in android

Tags: android, image, android-sqlite

I am new to android. I would like to know how to retrieve stored images from a database. No add or delete functionality. I want to retrieve already stored images from a database. Please help me achieve this.

Comment: How are they stored in the db?

Answer (score 0):

This answers assumes that you are retrieving images from a database in another app (because you'd already now how to retrieve images from a database that you created).

If the database is within another application, you must use a content provider. This [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) will redirect you to the official documentation. It covers all you will need to know about content providers.

In the most basic terms ever, to use a content provider you must first ask permission. Then you query the application that stores the database rather than the database itself (note: the application you query in turn queries the database). Therefore, you must have documentation that will provide predefined methods that must be used.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what really you want.

But if you finding a simple way to store image to database, you can try **base64** image, it is like a **string** so simple store and read it in/from database.

To display base64 image on html, use can you

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,base64_data_here"/>
```

Reference to more information:

- To convert your image to base64

> [How to convert a image into Base64 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-to-convert-a-image-into-base64-string)

- To convert base64 to image:

> [How to convert a Base64 string into a BitMap image to show it in a ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837110/how-to-convert-a-base64-string-into-a-bitmap-image-to-show-it-in-a-imageview)