# Send image via json in android

Tags: android, json, image

Hi I am working with android.I want to send an image from server to android and I had done it with sending url from server.How can I send an image from server to android app via json?? is it possible??

Comment: you send the url with the json. parse the json retrieve it and download the image

Comment: For that you can use JSON parsing and retrieve your image url through it and download that image to your android app.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if you can convert your image at your server to a Base64 encoding string. Then you can send the string to your app via JSON.

You can use Apache Common IOUtils:

```
Base64.encode(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(imageFile));
```

On your app you can convert the string to image, example in this link
[How to convert a Base64 string into a BitMap image to show it in a ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837110/how-to-convert-a-base64-string-into-a-bitmap-image-to-show-it-in-a-imageview)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send binary data within Json but you have to escape the binary data (UTF-8 encoding and use Base64.) This will increase the data size. Why not just include the path in JSON and fetch/load it?