# How to put image dynamically in a Card?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I am querying the images using REST Service where I receive it in a `Base64 encoded` format. How do I convert it to `Bitmap`, and then put it on the Card? I am using `CardScroller`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without giving any code, what you ask is an entire tutorial on how to create and populate a CardscrollerView...

You will need to convert your Base64 image to an imageview first, here is a similar topic : [Base64 To Imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837110/how-to-convert-a-base64-string-into-a-bitmap-image-to-show-it-in-a-imageview/4837293#4837293)

Then you will need to populate your imageview in your CardScrollView like this example, here is an example : [CardScrollView Tutorial](http://www.toptal.com/google-glass/building-your-first-glass-app-a-tutorial-for-aspiring-google-glass-developers)

Comment: ur awsme :) I just needed the image to be displayed..it seems a real simple solution...thanks :)