# How to load an image from dataurl in android imageview?

Tags: android, imageview, data-url

I have the following dataurl

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAARgAAADSCAMAAACmVC/YAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyJpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuMC1jMDYwIDYxLjEzNDc3NywgMjAxMC8wMi8xMi0xNzozMjowMCAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIiB4bWxuczp4bXBNTT0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wL21tLyIgeG1sbnM6c3RSZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9zVHlwZS9SZXNvdXJjZVJlZiMiIHhtcDpDcmVhdG9yVG9vbD0iQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENTNSBNYWNpbnRvc2giIHhtcE1NOkluc3RhbmNlSUQ9InhtcC5paWQ6ODMwQTFBMjFDRkYxMTFFNDk1QzNFODQ3NkZGQzk2MEUiIHhtcE1NOkRvY3VtZW50SUQ9InhtcC5kaWQ6ODMwQTFBMjJDRkYxMTFFNDk1QzNFODQ3NkZGQzk2MEUiPiA8eG1wTU06RGVyaXZlZEZyb20gc3RSZWY6aW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmlpZDo4MzBBMUExRkNGRjExMUU0OTVDM0U4NDc2RkZDOTYwRSIgc3RSZWY6ZG9jdW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRpZDo4MzBBMUEyMENGRjExMUU0OTVDM0U4NDc2RkZDOTYwRSIvPiA8L3JkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbj4gPC9yZGY6UkRGPiA8L3g6eG1wbWV0YT4gPD94cGFja2V0IGVuZD0iciI/PhgPDfMAAAA2UExURZkAAMzMzJsEBLNmZqYzM5wNDcnAwL+amqMmJsOmprmAgKxNTcazs58aGrZzc6lAQK9aWryNjUb/MzMAAAbVSURBVHja7J3blqMgEEV1kJsg6v//7KQ7ilwKYnfnBXL208Q4vRYnxQGK2/APkAwAAAAAAAD8CrUxNjPGptL3hjHnGDOq9Bemx1/YHy8sHamyzGL0zLk2U/i9IF4YuLvesKYTWbgbY3Yef7+P9ReGwYjoe626qEQ6LfcowoIpMdZfGIY5+76DoKHKHRacU9+Pgtd0ebA2X480Ve7R+oLLSwwpL5FkUI9I5Vr34PPXFm7ij6bHy+BO3/We/B1EykeHd+DlVEs+GiS1iVy5FpnSuuONeImFM2l8zKm0LAlB00PABJ5yFnx7fhTRpy+247+cAZMKdSqjm3YY4tfVYVU4XrDhf7LPZ4cLscyNzyhsuc028a8fhUxYyJmIsimSKQip069d+zUpKvdZN3ggDAtfYKEw0duxtLZhYWT+cw9D2OyoV8JsRBvEY/9ukbTpzR8S5ZZBVTtjLlLutKm1eWEUVZWen/bsxz++3yOVYg0cpVaLwlQM+fikedoam6g5j1sgRlhX+9i4VEdI6KO6TTquXJS0p2XLrnRhySjQ92S1Y8z5D5yqdz0Ls45pW8tlPkSUPJZA0AONjnTxSYiwoZqSzIOYXsTG0p0wJh1cf0UMyzIygvF6pelMGD4T2ZaVTlStHyTMleO8GucwCyUfXJ/MpwgTpMSDXLfyqhwhsnptVFkY1ZEwQY1hefc/fMbC6jbVmmvRQbjsVJNzlZsaRH43XLzvfkwQLvGUkSMTCDZouYisgzem5oW53MWuN9ISUarBUuNz1n6mKu7ZOn4nLREZi6Qy33vzo+twLERNrL4WhgwOMowaTeLRv+9rYVbChRbSeBr1F0Hm9DU5RWSC+RFO5Lq2DuZPpryvS5hFknGawxyezF+xpGU3mZUSvD6oVFS/1kSvLGnAtJwL96UqTadyIqC8Wx/PRPLKmbloOrGpzzQCQWRB1vvvZJPMxNkR1kucvGk5YJaxwjM8fJ9YbhPn0ybzFTK+vZ/ZxjSR0Wk4L1UU5hpep6g86xetNuuira4Iky6vo9aSrS9WXDXcuasIQ63RG23c60mTwo3Hy01hHvZqE1myTvIS/yXXuC6DYRWivMTstbEzOSV9LQW2rqcl0Hc6yd/U2rjvF/gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAH7IdixtjXannItg1w8WxhBniq59rIr/I3OmwiLGHraC/hW/a2s/n+ixg419b8AHyCGES4X6WNZom+2anff7uZwxooP4EQq6XK7irn8aqDIE+yInN3Z58t+v8cdEd7J/7X2wvs5JfyN7Vyfrv9Nmgl2RDHIEKOpCAhAMmj5+KJBGjCC26IPoIhCMBqiKhPFjRHI4BmwmMRgNmyENRiwMNkMZzHadkgGbCQzmSwyfz0PewRvMMx2+jshUJT2YY+jokHqIDcalQn14sspk7ZAaYTPBECmwlA02c9WbKAcjYTPzSJ2z6pPjn2sz00GS5F3O5+jMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAL/n7nOs09bYCYvG3+WlXLNtCzWNnf0HspptVEEu08HuUhcCZy7tyeHRNnuhkhfSW3etH3vF4rP6ghFHJJW/JPeuNMhMX21ErX8q3exMXRXawqIi+KzJThu/FDW4LdZNk8/u9/OWXYmds1qWNj8aWd/75qxC1
```

is there a way to load the dataUrl in imageview?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First you need to [convert the Base64 encoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837110/how-to-convert-a-base64-string-into-a-bitmap-image-to-show-it-in-a-imageview) to a Bitmap.
Code snippet below from linked question:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode("Your Base64 String", Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

When that is done you have your bitmap in `bitmap`
Assuming your `imageView`is defined as `R.id.image_view`
Then just do as you would with any other bitmap:

```
ImageView imageView;
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: there is a out of memory error when doing the above decoding

Comment: @Jyothish Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Since I was getting the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
```

, I used the following workaround:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import java.io.InputStream
import android.util.Base64

...
val imageData: ByteArray = Base64.decode(dataUri.substring(dataUri.indexOf(",") + 1), Base64.DEFAULT)
val inputStream: InputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(imageData)
val bitmap: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)

imageViewComponent.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

Perhaps it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Just decode the Base64 image encoding using [Base64.decode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#decode(byte[],%20int)) method to receive a byte array, and then create the `Bitmap` using [BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int)) method.

Comment: i have the dataurl in a variable and no need to fetch it from database or network.Do i need to do the decoding in a asynctask or doing it in the main thread will affect the performance?

Answer (score 0):

If you take the Base64 part of the input, it can easily be converted to a Bitmap via this:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode("your base64 string", Base64.DEFAULT); 
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Answer (score -1):

get base64 string in String variable decode

String encodedImage;// set base64 string value in this string
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);