# How to send a bitmap from Android Studio to WebService (asp.net api controller)

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services

In my Android Studio app I can take pictures which are saved in a bitmap.
This bitmap I want to send to my web service (asp.net c#) so that I can save it there.
I am working with retrofit and until now I was able to send my Complex datatype (Info) to my Controller. 
Now the only way I see to send my bitmap to my web service is to convert it to a String which I did like this:
[How to convert a Base64 string into a BitMap image to show it in a ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837110/how-to-convert-a-base64-string-into-a-bitmap-image-to-show-it-in-a-imageview)

but now when I add the bitmap as string, my controller isn´t reached anymore.
Even when I make it url conform. Any Idea why or if there is an other way to send a bimap?

Comment: why not just use the multipart form data content type and just upload the image

Comment: @Bhargav that isn´t working also. Tried.... is not hitting the funktion in Controller

Comment: which tech stack are you using for the web service

Comment: I am using retrofit for client and asp.net api for web service

Comment: post the webservice code and the retrofit code too please

Answer (score 0):

You can use Image Upload library. See this link:
https://github.com/alexbbb/android-upload-service