# Byte[] of an image, returns null when placed in BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()

Tags: java, android, json, bitmap, byte

I'll try to explain my problem as clear as I can. 
I have an web api that returns me an byte[].
[image]

When I convert that to a Byte[] and feed it to BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray() it gives me null, but it's an valid byte array. 
[image]

These images returned by the web api are user submitted logos of their companies and I can't control the formats on which they are uploaded. Is there a way to make it onto a valid bitmap or drawable?

**Edit**: I realized I had an " at start and at the end of the string, I removed them in my work code and I'm still having the issue.

Comment: Looks like it's Base64 encoded. Did you try decoding it thusly? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837110/how-to-convert-a-base64-string-into-a-bitmap-image-to-show-it-in-a-imageview

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MikeM. this got me through but when I set the bitmap to an image view, it's all blank... But at least bitmap factory returns a valid bmp

Comment: I solved the issue for the blank image. Thanks @Mike M. I upvoted your reply, but cannot mark it as the answer.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the edit to your comment earlier. I just went ahead and closed it as a duplicate of that question, since it had the code you needed. Thanks, anyway. Glad you got it working. Cheers!