# Prasing long string of charcters for image to display

Tags: android, android-image

I am hitting a web service and saving parsing all the data to display in a list view. All is working fine, but now I need to parse the ThumbnailData tag. I am unable to find any information on how to parse a string like this to make it an image to display.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        PeepWithPic peepWithPic = getItem(position);
        final AppViewHolder holder;

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contact_cardview_layout, parent, false);
            holder = new AppViewHolder();

            holder.tvFirstName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personFirstName);
            holder.tvLastName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personLastName);
            holder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personTitle);
            holder.mPeepPic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);

            if (peepWithPic != null) {
                holder.tvFirstName.setText(peepWithPic.getFirst_name());
                holder.tvLastName.setText(peepWithPic.getLast_name());
                holder.tvTitle.setText(peepWithPic.getPayroll_title());

                Bitmap parsedImage = base64ToBitmap(peepWithPic.getThumbnailData()); //error here also
                holder.mPeepPic.setImageBitmap(parsedImage);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
        return convertView;
    }

    public class AppViewHolder {
        private TextView tvFirstName;
        private TextView tvLastName;
        private TextView tvTitle;
        private ImageView mPeepPic;

    }

    private Bitmap base64ToBitmap(String peepPic) {
        byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(peepPic.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT); //error here 
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
    }
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
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It 's an Base64 string. You can use this link to do this:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

[How to convert a Base64 string into a BitMap image to show it in a ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837110/how-to-convert-a-base64-string-into-a-bitmap-image-to-show-it-in-a-imageview)

Comment: I would do this onRepsonse not in the listView adapter?

Comment: I have done the Base64 converting and I am getting null in my ListViewAdapter. I have debugged and the string is going through the decoding. Not sure why I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] java.lang.String.getBytes()' on a null object reference. I updated original post to show the code and two places I am getting the errors

Comment: Is `encodedImage` not empty? You can set your `encodedImage` as your long string above for testing.

Comment: So imageAsBytes as the long string I copied earlier first. Then in the base64ToBitmap method, its returning imageAsBytes: {-10, 62, 0, 1, 4, -92, 100, -108, 96, 0, + 13636 more}. When i go to next debug point the Bitmap parsedImage = base64ToBitmap(peepWithPic.getThumbnailData()); the getThumbnailData has the old string not that new imageAsBytes. Then next debug point has the holder.mPeepPic... as parsedImage: null.

Comment: Do you test 1 image with your base64 string? If it 's ok, you can change to your adapter. Because your rest service returns image as base64 string, you need to preprocess base64 string before you can load it to ImageView. I think has 2 options to do this: 1 Save your base64 string( bitmap) as a image file in your phone and load it to imageview. 2 return ThumbnailData as a link, you can use Picasso/Glide or any libs to load that image.

Comment: Sorry not fully understanding what you mean here. I am not sure why I am getting the ByteArray in the base64ToBitmap method but then its null back in the getView.

Comment: With the Base64 class import, what one is it suppose to be? I think its the import I am using as this is null. It it suppose to be from the android.util package or am I importing the wrong one?