# Convert base64 string to image in Android

Tags: android

I have converted an image into base64 through an online site.
I went through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35799454/5714364) to hold base64 string in a String. But i get an error saying
    Error:(38, 36) error: constant string too long

Please let me know how to convert base64 into an image (bitmap) in android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
     //encode image(from image path) to base64 string
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathOfYourImage);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

     //encode image(image from drawable) to base64 string
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourDrawableImage);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: The question is how to convert base64 into an image (bitmap) in android, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

First of all check your string

http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Try this way to convert.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView image =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

        //encode image to base64 string
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

        //decode base64 string to image
        imageBytes = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        image.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);
    }
}
```

http://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2016/10/android-convert-image-base64-string-base64-string-image.html