# convert base64 data to image

Tags: android

Is there any way that I can convert a base64 String to image in Android? I am receiving this base64 String in a xml from the server connected through socket.

I recuperate a image from json object and i need to set image of  item RecyclerView
someone have  a tuto to retrive img and set in RecyclerView

```
    String Img = currentobject.getString("image");               
     byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(Img.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                                ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_user);
                                image.setImageBitmap(
                                        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length)
                                );

persone= new persone(id,name,img);
personnes.add(persone);

    //in my adapter 
    //i use this 
     Glide.with(context)
                    .load(persone.getImage())
                    .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                    .into(holder.thumbnail);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294821/convert-base64-string-to-image-in-android

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```