# Best way to send an image path url from local PC to an Android app over TCP?

Tags: java, android, tcp, android-button, data-transfer

I have an offline system that integrates with an Android app over a `TCP` connection.

I need to get an image stored in the system (in the format of `"c:/user/me/img/img.png"`) from the android app and display it inside a button (not imageButton as the button could be either text, or image with a text).

I've tried sending the raw url but I couldn't load the image from the app even after converting it to a bitmap and drawable. So I thought maybe the raw url idea is not a good idea. Do I send a different format `(URI?)` from the pc to the app? What is the best working way to go about this?

Cheers

**EDIT**

exchange of data between the two are completely fine. i just need a way for the app to be able to display the image from the `app's local database`, which was populated with the string data that was sent by the pc over tcp. im just not sure what to send

Comment: `c:/user/me/img/img.png` is not a URL.

Comment: Here are two options, either write a client program in java for the system to send it over tcp using a serversocket and a output stream. Or run a simple web server such as apache web server to host the picture and then call the url of the pc/server.

Comment: @SteelToe I've done the first option and used it in many other circumstances, but for this particular case, does converting the local image to a bytestring before sending it out would be best?

Comment: @arzwng If you don't want to go the first route, I would recommend going with the apache web server as it doesn't require much code and works quite well

Comment: @SteelToe ah, second route is not favorable as I only need to retrieve the images once and cache it in the app's local database for future use

Comment: I think server socket is the best option for your requirement

Comment: @arzwng I understand but I don't believe that there is a easier way, please correct me anyone if I am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url which you are sending is a local path of image in your system. 
When you send it to Android it can load it.

Do one thing just [convert your image to Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-to-convert-a-image-into-base64-string) string and send it to Android over socket connection.

Once you receive Base64 string, just [decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837110/how-to-convert-a-base64-string-into-a-bitmap-image-to-show-it-in-a-imageview) it and set it your imageview.

Comment: Convert it to Base64 why?

Comment: Simple url can't be sent. 
Either directly convert your image to Bitmap bytearray and send it.