# Android Volley retrieving an Image

Tags: android, mysql, android-volley

How can I retrieve an Image from MySql database using volley?
I saved my images in a file in the directory and saved the url in the database.

Comment: Have you tried Volley's ImageRequest?

Comment: I made a String request and get the url of the image from the database and tried to display it using picasso but sadly it did'nt work. Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                                .load("http://10.0.2.2/Shop&Go/image/222.jpg")
                                .into(propic);

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the image file into base64 string while fetching and decode it into bitmap image.

[Original Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837110/how-to-convert-a-base64-string-into-a-bitmap-image-to-show-it-in-a-imageview)

Comment: I made a String request and get the url of the image from the database and tried to display it using picasso but sadly it did'nt work. Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()) .load("10.0.2.2/Shop&Go/image/222.jpg") .into(propic);

Comment: Is that url public/ accessible from the web? Possibly not, save the images in your web directory and check.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If yes please share the solution for others.