# Display BLOB image from mysql to android using volley

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

I am able to upload an image to mysql database using this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <?php

require_once 'include/db-function.php';

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    $filename = $_POST['category_name'];
    if (getimagesize ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ) ==FALSE){
        echo failed;
    } else{
    $name =addslashes( $_FILES['image']['name']);
        $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents(addslashes($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])));
    saveimage($filename, $image);

    }
    }


function saveimage($filename,$image){
    global $connection;
    $query = "insert into categories(category_name,image) values('$filename','$image')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if ($result){
        echo "success";
    }else{
        echo "failed";
    }

}   

?>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='file' name='image' />
Enter image name :<input id="category_name"type="text" name="category_name">
<input  type= "submit" value='Save name' name='upload'>
</form> 
</body>
```

I'm then trying to fetch the data from the database to JSON array with the following:

```
<?php require 'include/db-connect.php';

$sql = "select * from categories";
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

$result = array();

if ($res != false) {
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    array_push($result, array(
            'category_id' => $row['category_id'],
            'category_name' => $row['category_name'],
            'image' => base64_encode($row['image'])
        )
    );
}

echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
}
mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

On the Android Side this is what I've done:

```
private void parseData(String response){
    try{
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Utils.JSON_ARRAY);
        ArrayList<CategoryModel> categories = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject data = result.getJSONObject(i);

            CategoryModel categoryModel = new CategoryModel();
            categoryModel.setImage(data.optString ("image"));
            categoryModel.setCategoryName(data.optString("category_name"));
            listCategories.add(categoryModel);

        }

    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    //Finally initializing our adapter
    adapter = new CategoryViewHolder(listCategories, this);
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);

    //Adding adapter to RecycleView
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and in the onBindViewHolder This is what I have...I'm really not sure what to use to set image. You could also assist me here.

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder.ViewHolder holder, int 
 position) {
    CategoryModel category = categories.get(position);
    String categories = "";


    holder.textView.setText(category.getCategoryName());
    //holder to setImage not sure about this part

}
```

I'm able to get the Category Name but not able to retrieve Image. Your Help will be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Please help me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563123/display-blob-image-from-mysql-to-android-using-volley-json-encoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to convert your base64 string  using Base64.decode  into a byte array and then make that  into a bitmap. and attach the bitmap on your imageView like this.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder.ViewHolder holder, int 
 position) {
    CategoryModel category = categories.get(position);
    String categories = "";


    holder.textView.setText(category.getCategoryName());
    //convert the image string int bytes like this
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(category.getImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap imgBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 

    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(imgBitMap);

}
```

NOTE! for more check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837110/how-to-convert-a-base64-string-into-a-bitmap-image-to-show-it-in-a-imageview)**

Comment: @SimpleProgrammer can you please share the full source code of image upload, download, and view to/from MySQL. thanks in advance