# Display BLOB image from mysql to android using volley (json encoded)

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-volley

Seniors please help me my code mentioned below,
this code is able to shows only text data but never image please help me.
i want to show also image with text data but i am fail. basically i am using recycle view to show MySQL data with blob image. please help me

php code

```
    <?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET') {

    include 'DatabaseConfig.php';

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

    //Checking if any error occured while connecting
 // Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);}

// Query to run
$query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM  customers_recovery.customer_registration');
// Create empty array to hold query results
$customelist = [];

// Loop through query and push results into $someArray;
while ($i = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   array_push($customelist, [
   //'id'   => $row['customer_id']
   'myid' => $i['customer_id'], 
   'mynam' => $i['customer_name'], 
   'myarea' => $i['area_id'], 
   'myproduct' => $i['product_id'], 
   'myhouse' => $i['house_no'],
   'myphone' => $i['phone_no'],
   'myaddress' => $i['address'], 
   //'mypic' =>   $i['picture']
   'mypic' => base64_encode($i['picture'])
   //'image' => base64_encode($row['image'])
   ]);}
 //displaying the result in json format 
   $jsonDATA = json_encode($customelist);
   echo $jsonDATA;
}
?>
```

made customers list in android

```
package customerrecovery.zaheer.app.activities;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import customerrecovery.zaheer.app.R;
import customerrecovery.zaheer.app.adapters.CustomerListAdapter;
import customerrecovery.zaheer.app.model.CustomerListBean;

import static customerrecovery.zaheer.app.common.RestfulIpService.customer_register_get_url;

public class CustomersList extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<CustomerListBean> mycustomerlist ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customers_list);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recylcerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mycustomerlist = new ArrayList<>();
        loadProducts();
    }

        private void loadProducts() {

            /*
             * Creating a String Request
             * The request type is GET defined by first parameter
             * The URL is defined in the second parameter
             * Then we have a Response Listener and a Error Listener
             * In response listener we will get the JSON response as a String
             * */
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, customer_register_get_url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {
                                //converting the string to json array object
                                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                                //traversing through all the object
                                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                    //getting product object from json array
                                    JSONObject jsonData = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                    //adding the product to product list
                                    mycustomerlist.add(new CustomerListBean(
                                            jsonData.getString("myid"),
                                            jsonData.getString("mynam"),
                                            jsonData.getString("myarea"),
                                            jsonData.getString("myproduct"),
                                            jsonData.getString("myhouse"),
                                            jsonData.getString("myphone"),
                                            jsonData.getString("myaddress"),
                                            jsonData.optString("mypic")
                                    ));
                                }

                                //creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
                                CustomerListAdapter adapter = new CustomerListAdapter(CustomersList.this, mycustomerlist);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    });

            //adding our stringrequest to queue
            Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
        }
}
```

Bean class in Android to get json data

```
package customerrecovery.zaheer.app.model;

import java.sql.Blob;

public class CustomerListBean {

    private String cid;
    private String cnam;
    private String carea;
    private String cproduct;
    private String chouse;
    private String cphone;
    private String caddress;
    private String cpic;


    public CustomerListBean(String cid, String cnam, String carea, String cproduct, String chouse, String cphone, String caddress, String cpic) {
        this.cid = cid;
        this.cnam = cnam;
        this.carea = carea;
        this.cproduct = cproduct;
        this.chouse = chouse;
        this.cphone = cphone;
        this.caddress = caddress;
        this.cpic = cpic;
    }

    public String getCid() {
        return cid;
    }



    public String getCnam() {
        return cnam;
    }



    public String getCarea() {
        return carea;
    }


    public String getCproduct() {
        return cproduct;
    }


    public String getChouse() {
        return chouse;
    }


    public String getCphone() {
        return cphone;
    }


    public String getCaddress() {
        return caddress;
    }


    public String getCpic() { return cpic; }
/*
    public void setCpic(String cpic) {
        this.cpic = cpic;
    }*/
}
```

Finally make Adapter class in android to show data

```
package customerrecovery.zaheer.app.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;

import customerrecovery.zaheer.app.R;
import customerrecovery.zaheer.app.model.CustomerListBean;

public class CustomerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomerListAdapter.CustomerListViewHolder> {

    private Context mCtx;
    private List<CustomerListBean> mycustomerlist;

    public CustomerListAdapter(Context mCtx, List<CustomerListBean> mycustomerlist) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.mycustomerlist = mycustomerlist;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomerListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_list_row, null);
        return new CustomerListViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomerListViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        CustomerListBean CustomerlistBean = mycustomerlist.get(position);

        //loading the image
        /*Glide.with(mCtx)
                .load(product.getImage())
                .into(holder.imageView);*/
        //viewHolder..setText(CustomerlistBean.getCnam());
        //viewHolder.textView.setText(CustomerlistBean.getCpic());
        //convert the image string int bytes like this



        viewHolder.customer_name.setText(CustomerlistBean.getCnam());
        viewHolder.customer_id.setText(CustomerlistBean.getCid());
        viewHolder.area_id.setText(CustomerlistBean.getCarea());
        viewHolder.product_id.setText(CustomerlistBean.getCproduct());
        viewHolder.house_no.setText(CustomerlistBean.getChouse());
        viewHolder.phone_no.setText(CustomerlistBean.getCphone());
        viewHolder.address.setText(CustomerlistBean.getCaddress());
//        Glide.with(mCtx).load(CustomerlistBean.getCpic()).into(viewHolder.imageView);
        try {
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(CustomerlistBean.getCpic(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap imgBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            //Glide.with(mCtx).load(imgBitMap).into(viewHolder.imageView);
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(imgBitMap);
       // viewHolder.imageView.invalidate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mycustomerlist.size();
    }


    class CustomerListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView customer_id, customer_name, area_id, product_id, house_no, phone_no, address;
        ImageView imageView;

        public CustomerListViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            customer_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cNam);
            customer_id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cId);
            area_id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cArea);
            product_id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cProduct);
            house_no = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cHouse);
            phone_no = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cPhone);
            address = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cAddress);
            //imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you able to get a file locally as a byte array and display that image. then you know that part is fine. if not make sure you can do that. if you can then the problem is in the encoding and storing portion.

Comment: sir i'm able to retrieve String Values from database but  BLOB Image create a problem on conversion  here __------------->>>>>>   try {
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(CustomerlistBean.getCpic(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap imgBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            //Glide.with(mCtx).load(imgBitMap).into(viewHolder.imageView);
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(imgBitMap);
       // viewHolder.imageView.invalidate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try and make sense out of this but this was the code that I used for my application

for my model, as you have called bean class

```
public class Categories {
private String categoryId,categoryName, categoryImage;

public String getCategoryImage() {
    return categoryImage;
}

public void setCategoryImage(String categoryImage) {
    this.categoryImage = categoryImage;
}

public String getCategoryId() {
    return categoryId;
}

public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
}

public String getCategoryName() {
    return categoryName;
}

public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
}

public Categories(String categoryId, String categoryName, String categoryImage) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
    this.categoryImage = categoryImage;
}

public Categories(){

    }

}
```

Then in my activity class this is what I did

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, 
CategoryAdapter.ItemClickListener {

private View rootView;

private ArrayList<Categories> categoryList;
private CategoryAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

private ProgressDialog loading;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Dashboard");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.dashboard_recycler);

    //Initializing the Categories list
    categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), categoryList, this);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    fetchData();

}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    fab.setCount(new Database(this).getCount());

}

private void fetchData() {
    loading = new ProgressDialog(this);
    loading.setMessage("Please wait...");
    loading.show();

    StringRequest req = new StringRequest(ServerURLs.ALL__CATEGORIES_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("Our response is ", response);
                    loading.hide();
                    loading.dismiss();
                    loading = null;
                    categoryList.clear();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(ServerURLs.JSON_ARRAY);
                        ArrayList<Categories> categories = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject data = result.getJSONObject(i);
                            Categories categoryModel = new Categories();
                            categoryModel.setCategoryId(data.optString("category_id"));
                            categoryModel.setCategoryImage(data.optString ("image"));
                            categoryModel.setCategoryName(data.optString("category_name"));
                            categoryList.add(categoryModel);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("SRD", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                loading.dismiss();
                new AlertDialog.Builder(DashboardActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("No Internet Connection")
                        .setMessage("Please connect to the Internet")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                fetchData();

                            }
                        }).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).show();

            }

            else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                loading.dismiss();
                new AlertDialog.Builder(DashboardActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("No Internet Connection")
                        .setMessage("It looks like your're having a problem with your internet connection and try again")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                fetchData();

                            }
                        }).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).show();
            }

            else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                loading.dismiss();
                new AlertDialog.Builder(DashboardActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Failed to connect to Server")
                        .setMessage("Check if you have Internet Access")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                fetchData();

                            }
                        }).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).show();
            }
            Log.e("SRD", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            loading.dismiss();
            loading = null;
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
   Controller.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }
}
```

And finally my adapter class

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
public Context context;
private Context mContext;

private List<Categories> categories;
private ItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

public CategoryAdapter(Context context, List<Categories> categories, ItemClickListener onItemClickListener){
    //Getting all the categories
    mContext = context;
    this.categories = categories;
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView category_image;
    public TextView category_name;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        category_image =  view.findViewById(R.id.category_image);
        category_name = view.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
    }
}

@Override
public CategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.category_menu, parent, false );
    MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Categories category = categories.get(position);
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(category.getCategoryImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(decodedString)
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .crossFade()
            .fitCenter()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(holder.category_image);

    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(holder.category_image, String.valueOf(decodedString));
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(holder.category_name, category.getCategoryName());
    holder.category_name.setText(category.getCategoryName());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onItemClickListener.onItemClick(holder.getAdapterPosition(), category , holder.category_image, holder.category_name);
        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return categories.size();
}

public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int pos, Categories categoryItem, ImageView shareImageView, TextView mTextView);
    }

}
```

That's pretty much it. Hope that helps you.