# how to show Base64 encoded image string in ImageView

Tags: android, android-studio, encoding, uiimageview, android-image

I am picking an image from gallery and converting into Base64 encoded string and sending to server

Below code for conversion to Base64:

```
encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

But when I get encoded String from server it don't get displayed in ImageView

Base64 encoded image string below:

> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
>                                                             AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
>                                                             AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCAi8CLwDASIA
>                                                             AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAAYDAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAgMEBQYHAQgJAAoL/8QAUxAAAgICAQMEAQMDAwMB
>                                                             AQAjAQIDEQQSBQYhIgAHEzEIFDJBI0JRCRVhFlJxM2IKFyRygUORGCWCoTRTkqKxJsHRGWPwwvEa
>                                                             J7LhNTZEc5PS8v/EABwBAAIDAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAIDAAEEBQYHCP/EAEsRAAIBAgUCBAMHAgUD
>                                                             AwIADwERAiExAAMSQVEEYQUicYEykaEGE0JSscHwYtEUcoLh8SOSsgcVotIzwhbyJEPiUyVzg7MX
>                                                             NKPT/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDv0GA82IXerC/vDjszjUK29oC5NMQNT+8MARSLvQJAjZomLIHAbcFG
>                                                             on7YWGOp7+LUF+T0YD3bS2CDehuRJ2cKCVLEKAmt12YLe2wsCI2ryA3JZZXUgIUS/Gyt7fICAe5I
>                                                             JI7fXEJegCTKs7IiqPbb9CK9LUBeOn/NXbYUfF9juSSujkCqzOxVSXLMPKh3ckKRKqsVPY1QFMdL
>                                                             ZCMJEKpRIjqVLRsEOvYjbYDtfdte5JFCizeiVayBez6hiqyBRS3YINlkYUlhh2vYbag+WXUljt9h
>                                                             VpSXUnc2opSAAAATe48hv+70eL1RJv8Avz/9Xt7DVlA+yAlSw7UNW3VrpQGNdi6kgUoKqB9rZr+L
>                                                             se0YZhpuQCKjUH9oo/tJ+gSCT+4gHxZCqFGQlqY0ANe+pI7kmit60LoKvcx+sNqQXIBSlIUAs1oC
>                                                             UUlvFtduy/x3EhJBuYgIJUd+70yAPr29L+hqyaNTqzhhsVtbVVa9GJ1D6fHs9k1VORS2MlWsx0Vd
>                                                             gS7FQh2CtalnqmBChVq2/tAHkRGhZAGXz+PdGWlayfpaCqGQMXJJ+/vYlT6NjmVuzmPeSVlJJMhC
>                                                             kXGQCupcECQmyvcUzWR6mCkkdK1VXLde6u13waw7OpLfIVWwQwBUsQu3bQWfA6kkqRsBXpRdspJW
>                                                             Q0FNGlQIGvdCbKsewIDqex2YgMUsikWS91saolv7gp+x+4MDRJruwqiColJmY7qGCkx/3AArQFsg
>                                                             QEESlB3P7fuyWKiC7xG3mNV76v1wGjUCShKjGxlIBar3Efw+hvga7OY7ZY7Id1Pke1rUbC3COFFx
>                                                             9+ylQBW3rEIHxlkILbgVQIUKbU/u+PxA3IUk7CxTFFYAi2YbEghWNr8njSr4kIyk2U7N96mgRepP
>                                                             hK6hI1CWtvsdTdKniwBoKYyCe7EjzBHl6tKqT99N6+/0eJGwCKQkikF6kUPPst8eLfK/xBS5qyyE
>                                                             qFcgqF3BBEhJ79jW1E/tX0ZuYyy6bkFrNkUFAOlEFtQHqjZclgKDOfQREDQoFUYgle7KtNJTJ90S
>                                                             AflP7iTdFvQiV/uAoBdr8TqCK2oMzaUSAD3F2e3qxMBHTFgUQI1L8TCpz/xgoyZsQ3ckr9uN98Hk
>                                                             FQojRgGUyDXc7PepUBjS1oxIAr9pUlifWHnC7na9CaNgsrfub7LLSrIq1GTTFTZJay0YMVUbKojc
>                                                             FSDp41Gg2I7qS5ANXQF33b0pjYDs2vgu3kFLFgihi5IJTUr8ax2dgdq/d6E6iAWQzq5IAvvxuOfT
>                                                             DMCRGXeR3fWWvjA3BDBmAOwZwU3Isa2ttZrViIFdlkQCxo7Gn1omNfkGzR6lmNgg6juwPfuIjVlZ
>                                                             hvopITxGwPcWSaoUB5G6P14sCElhalkbxsnxbY6gsQa1p0gBF0h7UBXeDUJNkupBFFs613K7KixM
>                                                             YL9y1KNSGkDVq5F+bIjB/AChsSbG1Cr9HA2GYoQynTTYnUqDsGAOpJuyi0xNBy2oBJaNg5U62wpy
>                                                             vkwtQAqsAoVV7luzCqogF29HogjNF3s9yzKxViSwALnQWKNVbEAEg7benxkJRKdRs1TYBWO53xMG
>                                                             S6s0SknW97VTey0QvfVlGpAYrsQQCxHcEUZgDkKrCNaCE2QaBUAMC/kf2tQJatFui3ovzBYAX9Oh
>                                                             UAttqwBpu5oqDQr78rs+ghSgZSwlJIdexFiyAvcsB+wCwQVJJqyX9XEgvSBQ6Qa780/gKfMwqoaK
>                                                             xYESNslkt9i9T5SAWFJeMkEsof8AgehIArswYM1bBSTtIvdAqktHp2BcKXKlmc6kAEltJYUqrLH3
>                                                             DoLRVUlVJBBve1sqCQLJPax6yYkIvUNZVSbNgCnDWathtrYG1WLrx9ACBIknbd1I4J3vquPrhOuC
>                                                             Wr6ji177P2+GmDEsUqrWySMQ7BdAr7bFWWrUEgqasU9jvZjuVIYFXjRSf6VsWYAHsRQoG+47fzf2
>                                                             fScgAUpYBO4LErTBT2U2zMCVvc9gLDWFX0pQkoDRDMtovYMfqtCexpCQ1CyoYoPoGjpPmqX6/JVr
>                                                             d1N6m+GRMTQBb/y+PRMr0uqhCUYeJKbAsfBk3dHUgt9lTqQP7j6PV0ZdFI7BVIBIJs0ACdvqqIvv
>                                                             TBqI9E2UC0LYFgS1j6O1ajXvqaS7sj+3z9DUvGQzMPlkcB9WoKLsALYJNkk/ZKkmz+80YMAiJCty
>                                                             Wgd1Vo04dqlgeyqqCNwrE6BFSggDKSWUtGGNKbPehZW719Z7Up7s+xsyFhQHcHUSXTEBFC2T33A7
>                                                             qMJ5+a3sBStbgLsCAe5vupDFv52Kr2BPrIDBQpe+xtyQQNe9K3YBiLK7mhRZv5DWIoDzAGIZEgiB
>                                                             R2NiTv7vEwavySMljwFEMviDS6gMCC72bD2SCKYkkFSM0q7U4dQzAKSGZCFH0xI7/IV2Bo0BTDa/
>                                                             AMUUIdaFliFY6qf7SratIwAP+dQWBOqn175kH7W8q/phAWRx3AJI7qCBqDX1ZO1OTDMA0AoYl8g2
>                                                             3RKFVW3CxMC8bGw7gCRr2bdQAjFgpOzBaWqq6Ki9ZPWVEaqjUQspVdDZBoOFHlZok3oKCkbp/cpJ
>                                                             jdHO306oCdSzAA0RqVAV6sHxH8GuzFSpChltpC8pUI+gLDsjtsAo2FKG7/zV9mo+hnJhaAVVMgoE
>                                                             nc13PyGAMkJH8pX8/tgaWyGygoghe/cglRRtltbCMAaNju1sCBEeQkbsssg+w48T2Cqq6vqSxBVj
>                                                             2AGxYs3oTBNuxZJGIIPc+XalO2y7L2JFfflROvryhh8fy9xuAHYozWStpJVsq7Gl7WDVg7PYxJdY
>                                                             6AwZcdzTelaetpMdVLUOzD0hBbMBnd96VUpaqY7VYxYKoxPfuLJcWSWs2K7kqoAv0CNttQra+QCq
>                                                             ftqWrBYliPEqWbs5Ygmg1kuQf3rZsAKKDEFgVJ2NElEHYA0SAewJPiDG21RjWQUVO0hAJDEgfQHa
>                                                             xdAkFB+5/VgipBBIJIqN6oImr9O18X8fZe9/+P46KA1qCCQQAV1bvXYWxsMy0R8gB796JHrLMX0U
>                                                             sA0ZBpAyh01VFDk/IZCGsDUuboABRt6wRZ2XYP2UBP3yqB3+0+kbsVYkMANNjqxFuV/cFF93plpS
>                                                             WBAP7VsMaFfz9dj3npt7aL/92/y74gmDbV5RUpD0qb/XvgRb49gybKWCEAHuBa/ZAX9zqdTTErYY
>                                                             +djpACCpU332oLdhQCp3vY9lYggCipHdfWY11VQ9hlUhKBKhQbVAbIYhvMMfuxqSO58pA2DXtRAq
>                                                             2JTuYzRZAG2A7WCwNXSqTQjclRJlWVRwRR/xWdqhATkzJ2MRUgIAVFPU8r5jhRnjOxEYDswYEsAo
>                                                             Ozgq9hlvVu/aiGIHrMrByERgEa1ZlCsr/wAFLpwrkldaP23agGBDGSpWJd9WYaFygYKC+yagFiuh
>                                                             Ut5XY7lvsiZNSg12VhsdCaCsA

and i display this encode image string in ImageView like this

```
String imageDataBytes = path;
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(imageDataBytes.getBytes(), Base64.URL_SAFE));
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
dashboard_img.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Above code I use **Base.64URL_SAFE** and **Default** also but not working. So please help me to fix this

Comment: `Bitmap image`. Have you checked if `bitmap` becomes `null`?

Comment: You shoud use Base64.DEFAULT at decoding too of course.

Comment: for **kotlin** you can use function as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68405903/4227328) asnswer.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh imageview with invalidate. Use this code snippet

```
try {
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imageDataBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,decodedString.length);
            dashboard_img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            dashboard_img.invalidate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Edit:** 
**I have checked your base64 string it is not a valid base 64.**

Comment: I have tested your base 64 string. It is unable to create image. check the screenshot https://imgur.com/bXNexyD

Comment: Think that it makes no sense to use that string as it is probably only a part of the base64 string. That string content is logged i think. And logging statements cut the string if it is too long.

Comment: Yeah!! It may be the reason if your base64 is not loading in image view first you have to check online here https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter. The above code is tested and working as expected!!!

Answer (score 0):

For set base64 image in imageView you can follow given code:

```
    String filePath;
    Bitmap bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(filePath)); // filePath is our BASE64 string
imgView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

And in-case your base64 string may be wrong, because this also can not decode on online decoder : https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: bitmap null why??

Comment: nothing is null,
Save or get your BASE64 image in FilePath variable , and convert it into bitmap and the last step is, just set this bitmap object into  your imageView.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(yourBase64String, 0, yourBase64String.length);
imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, customWidth, customHeight, false));
```