# Load base64 string into imageview using picasso

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I am new in android development.I have a PNG base64 local string image that stored in a variable and I want to show it on ImageView using Picasso.but picasso only get 'Resources, assets, files'.So How can I load My image?

Comment: "I have a base64 local string image" -- why is it base64-encoded? "So How can I load My image?" -- decode it first, then load it.

Comment: how to decode it and load by picasso?

Comment: You would decode it yourself. Picasso is not responsible for doing that.

Comment: I know that.but how to decode it and then load it using picasso?

Comment: You might wish to edit your question and provide much more details about the nature of your "base64 local string image". For example, what is the type of the image: PNG, JPEG, something else? Where is this "local string": a variable in memory, a file on the filesystem, something else? For example, if the answers are "PNG" and "a variable", you would not use Picasso, but instead use `BitmapFactory`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4837110/115145

Comment: i have edited it

Comment: You do not need Picasso. Use `BitmapFactory` to create a `Bitmap` to use in your `ImageView`.

Comment: i want to avoid from memory leak.so as i searched picasso handle these kind of problems.

Comment: Picasso has little to do with memory leaks. `BitmapFactory` also has little to do with memory leaks.