# Retrieve a list of images from the Database and display them using a ListView?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have some images in a database. The images are sent to Android Studio in the base64 format from the database using an API. How can I display these images using a `ListView`.

Comment: Please post what have you tried.

Comment: There is answer how to convert the [Base64 to Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4837293/10182897).

Comment: Which database/API?

Comment: *images are sent to android studio* -> How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use method to decode Bitmap from Base64 string to Bitmap:

Kotlin version:

```
fun getBitmapFromBase64(String input) : Bitmap {
    val decodedBytes = Base64.decode(input, 0)
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length)
}
```

Java version:

```java
public Bitmap getBitmapFromBase64(String input){
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
}
```

after that you can set this method:

```
youImageView.setImageBitmap(/*your bitmap*/)
```

in your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your base64 value with encodedImage.

```
  val encodedImage = "data:image/jpeg;base64,..."
        val decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT)
        val decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.size)

        Glide
            .with(this)
            .load(decodedByte)
            .into(<Your ImageView>)
```