# Incorrectly displayed base64 image in an ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, base64, imageview

I am working on an Android project where I need to retrieve a base64-encoded image from an API and display it in an ImageView. However, I am encountering a problem where the image is not displayed correctly. When I log the base64 string, I noticed that it appears incomplete compared to the string I obtain from Postman.

```kotlin
val data = response.data as? MasterDataModel ?: return
val supportedLogos = data.supportedLogo
    
val imageViews = listOf(binding.imgOne, binding.imgTwo, binding.imgThree, binding.imgFour)
    
for (i in 0 until minOf(supportedLogos.size, imageViews.size)) {
    val base64String = supportedLogos[i].logo
    base64String?.logDebug("BASE64IMAGE")
    val uri = Uri.parse(base64String)
    imageViews[i].setImageURI(uri)
    imageViews[i].visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

I have confirmed that the base64 string obtained from the API is valid, I tested with Postman and it displays correctly when tested using online base64 viewers.

Why isn't the data being displayed correctly in the ImageView? Are there any common pitfalls or additional steps I should consider when working with base64 images in Android?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you receive the Base64 completely but your mistake is the conversion of base64 to bitmap which you didn't do it.

So please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4837293/4592885) answer and aware of removing "data:image/png;base64," at the beginning of your Base64 string.

---

About the incomplete log i should say that every log message has a limit of 4KB if you want to bypass this limitation you can split your String into some chunk each less than 4KB then print them.